# Is it possible to pass JavaScript values ​to SCSS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

Like this

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      themeColor: " #ffffff",
    }
  },
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
$importedColor: themeColor  // javascipt variable


.btn {
  background: $importedColor;
}
.squre {
  border: 1px solid $importedColor;
}
</style>
```

Either way, I want to be able to choose the theme color in JavaScript.

Is it possible?

Comment: What if you used CSS variables and used Javascript to update those? https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you create a [Sass variable](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) that points to a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) which you then set with JavaScript:

**SCSS:**

```
:root {
  --my-custom-color: brown;
}

$importedColor: var(--my-custom-color);

body {
    background-color: $importedColor;
}
```

**JS:**

```js
function setBackgroundColor(color) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--my-custom-color', color);
}
```

I haven't tested this specific code shown above, but I have done this same type of thing in projects and had it work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I read that it is possible in Vue 3 and it's still experimental.

You can do it like this:

```
<template>
<div class="text">Hello</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
data(){
   return{
      color: "red"
   }
}
}
</script>

<style vars="{ color }">
.text {
color: var(--color);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Vue3 css variable injection   https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041295/14241212